# Specifying the raster layer name in processing qgis:rastercalculator

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, raster-calculator

I have a `QgsRasterLayer` and want to process it in a processing script with `qgis:rastercalculator`. How can I customize the name under which the layer is referenced in the expression? It seems that QGIS uses the file's basename but I would like to explicitly specify it myself.

This is working:

```
raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer("//tmp/my_file.tif")

parameters = {
    'EXPRESSION': "my_file@1 * 2",
    'LAYERS': [raster_layer],
    'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT',
}

processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:rastercalculator", parameters)
```

But instead of having to hard-code the file's basename in the expression (`my_file`) I would like to use an arbitrary identifier, e.g. `raster_a`. How can I do this?

I already tried these possible options but neither of them had an effect on the reference usable in the expression:

- Setting `raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer(..., baseName="test")` on instantiation
- `raster_layer.setName("test")`
- `raster_layer.setShortName("test")`
- `raster_layer.setTitle("test")`

Comment: Related bug: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/29402#issuecomment-1107449313

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that there is a canonical solution to this issue, but here are a couple of workarounds to avoid hardcoding the file name into the raster calculator expression.

Firstly, I found that if you add the layer to the project instance (which you can do without adding it to the table of contents by setting the `addToLegend` argument to `False`), then remove it after running the calculation, then the layer name passed to the `QgsRasterLayer` constructor is recognized.

```py
raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer("//tmp/my_file.tif", 'Test_layer')

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(raster_layer, False)

parameters = {
    'EXPRESSION': "Test_layer@1 * 2",
    'LAYERS': [raster_layer],
    'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT',
}

processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:rastercalculator", parameters)

QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(raster_layer)
```

Alternatively, if you don't like this approach you could always just retrieve the file name from the file path string and insert it dynamically into the expression string. The following should work:

```py
from pathlib import Path

file_path = "//tmp/my_file.tif"

raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer(file_path)

raster_name = Path(file_path).stem

parameters = {
    'EXPRESSION': f"{raster_name}@1 * 2",
    'LAYERS': [raster_layer],
    'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT',
}

processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:rastercalculator", parameters)
```

Comment: Thank you! Adding the layer to project feels a bit icky but seems like a decent workaround. The filename stem won't work because I might be a user who loves filenames like `this (name is evil".tif` and that would not work in expressions. I'll leave the question open for now, maybe there is some proper way.